# Palindromes with python

Tags: python, palindrome

Trying to use a book to learn python. Here is one of the exercises I'm struggling with.

> 3.12 (Palindromes)  A palindrome is a number, word or text phrase that reads the same backwards or forwards. For example, each of the following five-digit integers is a palindrome: 12321, 55555, 45554 and 11611. Write a script that reads in a five-digit integer and determines whether it’s a palindrome. [Hint: Use the // and % operators to separate the number into its digits.]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Sorry but we don't do "any help", you have to be more specific what you don't know how to do and show what you've already tried. Or you can type "python number palindrome" into Google Search, this is a very common exercise and you can find literally hundreds of solutions.

Comment: You could post this on https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @KingofNoobz Is the hint something we need to implement into our answers?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Program Explanation

1. User must first enter the value of the integer and store it in a variable.
2. The value of the integer is then stored in another temporary variable.
3. The while loop is used and the last digit of the number is obtained by using the modulus operator.
4. The last digit is then stored at the one’s place, second last at the ten’s place and so on.
5. The last digit is then removed by truly dividing the number with 10.
6. This loop terminates when the value of the number is 0.
7. The reverse of the number is then compared with the integer value stored in the temporary variable.
8. If both are equal, the number is a palindrome.
9. If both aren’t equal, the number isn’t a palindrome.
10. The final result is then printed.

```
n=int(input("Enter number:"))
temp=n
rev=0
while(n>0):
    dig=n%10
    rev=rev*10+dig
    n=n//10
if(temp==rev):
    print("The number is a palindrome!")
else:
    print("The number isn't a palindrome!")
```

Answer (score -2):

I don't know answering a question will go against the code of conduct of not. But here we go.

If the integer is always five digits then you can do it like followings:

```
def check_palindrome(number):
    number = str(number) # Will make the number string

    if number[0]==number[-1] and number[1]==number[-2]:
        return True
    else:
        return False

print(check_palindrome(12321))
print(check_palindrome(55555))
print(check_palindrome(12345))
```

Answer:

```
True
True
False
```